# AWS: Only give permissions to create / read backups but not to delete

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to set up a backup system where every PC should be able to write it's own backups to a AWS S3 bucket and also to read from that bucket, but not to delete it.

Thus, in case the PC get's hacked, there is no chance of deleting any backups from the S3 bucket.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I already created multiple IAM users, but there is a jungle of "AWS permissions" I can choose from so I'm kind of lost ...

[image]

Note: Even when I enter the filter keyword "backup" the result is 5 permission policies and I'm not sure which one to pick...

**Update**
using @luk2302 's comment: I chose

Users -> some IAM Username -> Permissions -> "Add Permission" -> "Create Inline Policy" -> "JSON"

then I copy paste the final json example from the [mentioned website](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
      "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","home/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
      "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":
                  [
                       "home/${aws:username}/*",
                       "home/${aws:username}"
                  ]
               }
        }
    },
    {
       "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
       "Action":["s3:*"],
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company/home/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

-> "Review Policy" -> Create a name for the policy

I dont really understand the json yet, but I'll let you know, when things are working...

Comment: You simply need to create your own policy, no predefined / managed policy will do that for you. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Comment: @luk2302 I updated my answer. I added the permission policy mentioned on the above website, but now I suffer from the fact that I cannot create paths with subfolders `aws s3api create-bucket --bucket myiamusername` gives me `Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]...`

Comment: What is the value you are using in place of `myiamusername`?